# reading parameters from bash profile file and passing to for loop and Calling function inside if statement inside for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .bash_profile file eg:

```
pdb[0]=pdbname1
pdb[1]=pdbname2
```

I want to read these parameters {pdb[@]} and pass it in for loop

```
echo ${pdb[@]}

 for A in ${pdb[@] }
 do
   if [pdb == 0]
    {
     PDB1();
    }
   else
    {
      PDB2();
    }
   fi
 done

private static void PDB1 ()
{
echo "expdp $username/$password@$DBname1 schemas=$schemas1 directory=$DUMP_DIR dumpfile=$dumpname1 logfile=$logname1"
EOF
}

private static void PDB2 ()
{
echo "expdp $username/$password@$DBname2 schemas=$schemas2 directory=$DUMP_DIR dumpfile=$dumpname2 logfile=$logname2"
EOF
}
```

This function call is not working properly

Comment: You've got Java syntax mixing with shell syntax. That's not how functions are defined nor called.

Comment: anyway, shouldn't the loop be if [ $A == 0 ] not [ pdb ==0 ]